# After refreshing the page sidebar menu is not collapsing in vue js 2(laravel + admin LTE + vue js 2)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, adminlte

'nav-item menu-is-opening menu-open' and 'display: block' these classes are not updating

I'm creating a sidebar in which nested levels are created which are open first time but doesn't close

Comment: First thing, make sure you are not loading bootstrap `js` file twice.

Answer (score 0):

The vuejs variable scope will go after the page refresh so you need to add the open and close status in local storage and you can get it by `localStorage.getItem('status')`;

```
methods: {
        toggleSideBar(status) {
            this.columnHidden[status] = !this.columnHidden[status];
            localStorage.setItem(status, true);
        }
    }
```